# TypeScript: Distinguish between unset and non-existent properties at runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class that has properties that are typed, but no defaults set, like:

```
export class Person {
   age: number;
}
```

At runtime, I have a JSON object who's properties I would like to test against the class signature to ensure it is one of the defined properties for the class.

```
{
   "age": 42,
   "propertyNotInClass": "oops!"
}
```

Is it absolutely necessary to set defaults to each property in the class in order to test this?

[edit]: In my current use case, I only need to know if the object is defined. Though I would be interested in knowing if the type could be tested. I know that's not a part of TypeScript natively, so would involve some kind of trickery.

Comment: "to test against the **class signature**" --- you first mentioned the type, then you're referring to runtime behaviour. So, what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is typescript since you used the typescript tag in your question.

The short answer is **no**, here is why:

Typescript is transpiled to JS. So at runtime, the notion of a `class` does not exist. If you want to check your JSON at runtime, you have to check the properties you want one by one.

here is what your `person` class would transpile to:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var Person = /** @class */ (function () {
        function Person() {
        }
        return Person;
    }());
    exports.Person = Person;
});
```

Here is what I mean by checking one-by-one, in this case, there is only one property

```
class Person {
    age: number;

    static isPerson(obj: Object): boolean {
      return !!obj.hasOwnProperty('age');
    }
}
Person.isPerson({ age: '32' }); // returns true
Person.isPerson({}); // returns false
```

you *could* get all properties via a transformer (have not tried this) read more here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13764

Comment: I thought so. Thanks.

Comment: "check the properties you want one by one" wouldn't do anything either, since the `age` property doesn't make it through transpilation if it's not set to a default.

Comment: I meant to say that you'd make a static util method to check if an object is a person by checking that it has an `age` property. not by getting the property from the Person class.

Comment: Huh. I'd like to see how people are doing that.

Comment: Cause my current solution just involves setting defaults, which are mostly `null` or empty arrays.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript can only help you catch type errors and enforce implementing certain interfaces at compile time. However, it cannot validate an object's structure at runtime. You have to check if the properties exist or if they have the desired value yourself using the vanilla JavaScript ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can bridge run-time and compile-time with TypeScript **user-defined type guards**.

```
function isPerson(obj: any): obj is Person {
  return obj && typeof obj.age === 'number';
}
```

Notice the special return type of `obj is Person`, which lets you create conditionals that narrow the type inference:

```
if (isPerson(maybePerson)) console.log(maybePerson.age);
else console.log('not a Person');
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards